# Лента времени на js

Tags: javascript, html, timeline

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать на js [вот это](http://time.graphics/ru/updates/new)

Куда копать в первую очередь? Там и скроллинг сделан. Какие технологии? Flash, Silverlights, Java, jQuery.. Может есть готовые js-библиотеки.

Спасибо.

Comment: js и canvas. Как хотите, так и реализуйте

Comment: Кстати, там начало эры неправильное, но это уже другая история

Comment: Надо с наименьшими затратами)

Comment: По времени или по деньгам? Эти две затраты взаимоисключающие :)

Comment: Умственными затратами))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном примере думаю, что реализовывался кастомный график.

Есть библиотеки по работе со временем, такие как [visjs](http://visjs.org/timeline_examples.html) и [MetricsGraphics.js](http://www.metricsgraphicsjs.org/).

Но если необходимо, что то кастомное, тогда придется учить [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) на хабре есть урок как сделать график с помощью d3 [d3.js](https://habrahabr.ru/post/303834/)

Вот пример с [visjs](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/items/htmlContents.html) немного похож на данный график

Comment: интересненько, спасибо